# É vantajoso utilizar o padrão MVC em aplicações pequenas?

Tags: mvc, arquitetura-de-software, design-pattern

Já li vários artigos relacionados ao MVC, suas vantagens na manutenção do códigos da reusabilidade e tudo mais.

Mas a dúvida é, em aplicações pequenas vale a pena utilizar este padrão, pois pelo que eu entendi, tem que ter todo um processo de planejamento na hora de criar uma aplicação utilizando este padrão.

Comment: Respondendo por minha experiência, que é pouca. Na empresa onde trabalho havia muita demanda de projetos pequenos. Como por exemplo um site no qual precisa de uma área para editar os itens do site, algo como banner, fotos etc, coisas simples. Quando passei a utilizar o padrão MVC, ficou muito mais rápido o desenvolvimento dos projetos e a manutenção dos mesmos. Acredito que seja vantajoso sim.

Comment: Só uma opnião que, seria como perguntar se é vantagem utilizar BDD para desenvolver aplicativos pequenos. Para quem não têm o hábito pode ser menos produtivo mas, depois de pegar a prática, você fica menos produtivo se não utilizar

Comment: O que seria uma aplicação pequena para você?

Comment: Um sistema que gerencia conteúdos de um site; cadastro de clientes; controle de contas

Comment: Eu pela minha experiencia tbm usaria pela rapida implementação e facil manutenção, mas uma das coisas que mais me motivam a usar ele e a facil integração com outros integrantes da equipe, como a nossa equipe aqui e dividida em designers e programadores fica muito facil a divisão.

Comment: Olha depende MUUITO do seu projeto, de quais seriam os seus objetivos, trabalho com MVC no Rails, pra mim é uma maravilha mas só atuei em projetos grandes com ele. Fora do MVC trabalhei com Web Forms em C#, (ASP .NET), e em várias vezes tentar com o MVC 3 ou 4 / 5 não seria muito indicado não, **pois às vezes ele pode adicionar uma complexidade desnecessária em seu projeto**. Portanto fique atento e saiba verificar as reais necessidades e características do seu objetivo! :D

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Na minha opinião vale sim, justamente pela organização e pela facilidade (teoricamente) em dar manutenção no código depois. Não sei se você já desenvolve utilizando algum framework que preza pelo MVC, mas quando se usa esses frameworks não importa o tamanho da aplicação, a ideia de se utilizar o MVC sempre está lá, nas pequenas e grandes aplicações.

Um bom exemplo é desenvolver uma aplicação utilizando RoR (Ruby on Rails), o MVC é tão bem aplicado que não há como fugir da organização dos modelos, views e controladores.

O planejamento realmente deve existir como você citou, mas isso independente de utilizar MVC ou não, certo?

Ah, e por mais que planejemos bem o desenvolvimento da aplicação, no mercado de trabalho todo mundo sabe que o tempo é valioso, de repente seu gerente aparece com uma ideia mirabolante, você precisa alterar e naquela altura do campeonato fugiu bastante do seu planejamento inicial...

Enfim, numa resposta simples e rápida acho que vale muito a pena manter o padrão MVC mesmo para aplicações pequenas, pelo fato de os frameworks que auxiliam no desenvolvimento sempre aplicarem o padrão.