# Como e para que usar MVC no PHP?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, mvc

Sempre fiz sites e sistemas sem problema usando o PHP estruturado, veio a curiosidade se é possível fazer um sistema em OOP por completo e se é mais vantajoso. Pesquisando achei o MVC, mas estou com dificuldades no entendimento e utilização do mesmo, todos tutoriais que achei usam o Composer, mas eu não tenho necessidade de usa-lo, pois não uso frameworks, nem bibliotecas, sempre faço em PHP puro.

A pergunta está clara no título, primeiro, para que usa-lo? Já que para sistemas de cadastros, edição e deletação o PHP estruturado se dá muito bem, no início achei que MVC serviria apenas para complicar o código, em troca deixa-lo mais organizado.

Outra coisa é que não estou conseguindo entender, principalmente a camada View, poderiam dar um exemplo, de crud de Cliente ou algo assim? Só pra ver se entendo.

Comment: MVC em PHP serve pro cara achar que tá fazendo o treco certinho pq ouviu na faculdade, ou no livro X que comprou nao sei aonde. Alguém viu isso em outra linguagem, e achou que no PHP ia dar certo fazer igual, mas equeceu que nem todas as linguagens funcionam da mesma maneira. Enquanto isso, o pessoal que entende de PHP faz scripts normais numa boa, e o treco sai mais rápido e dá menos manutenção. Academicismo em linguagem de script só faz sentido se realmente há necessidade. 80% a 90% dos códigos que eu vejo com  MVC e OOP no PHP são shows de horror. Os outros 10 a 20% não são pra qq um.

Comment: [O que é MVC?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/55486/91), [Como implementar o padrão MVC em PHP](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/63511/91) e [É vantajoso utilizar o padrão MVC em aplicações pequenas?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/28208/91)

Comment: PS: Votei positivo na pergunta, pois é uma dúvida válida. Meu primeiro comment é um protesto contra as modinhas, e não contra a pergunta. Que, aliás, acho que deveria ser feita por cada programador que inventa de adotar alguma prática.

Comment: Só citei frameworks por causa do uso do Composer na maioria dos tutoriais de MVC que vi. Concordo completamente com o @Bacco (exceto sobre a OOP, que em PHP é bom para criar bibliotecas, fora isso foi perca de tempo dos desenvolvedores da linguagem), pra mim mais vale um código bem estruturado, e organizado que seguir uma 'regra' que te dá mais trabalho. Pelo que entendi, então é meio que uma perca de tempo. Obrigado pelos comentários, vou esperar repostas, mas só pelos comentários já tomei a decisão de não usar MCV em PHP.

Comment: @Bacco você está certo mesmo. Meu professor inseriu esse conceito no php pra gente, no início parecia algo "estiloso", legal, mas depois percebi que não tinha vantagem, pelo menos pra trabalhos pequenos e acadêmicos. É um modismo acadêmico inserir um conceito de qualquer jeito sem se aprofundar nele.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## introdução

MVC é a sigla para Model View Controller, é um padrão de arquitetura utilizado como forma de estruturação geral de código que gera uma interface para o usuário (html/css/js no caso de php). A ideia central é separar a sua aplicação em três componentes lógicos:

- model. Aqui fica a parte da aplicação que lida com a lógica das sua entidades, os códigos que conhecem como elas funcionam (o "domínio do problema" ou as "regras de negócio" do sistema se você gosta de [buzzwords](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buzzword)) e que sabem como aplicar validações, conversões e interargir com o banco de dados ou a camada de persistência.
- view. Esta camada é responsável pela exibição da interface gráfica e a interação com o usuário. Cada "view" é uma representação visual do seu "model", assim caso tenhamos um "ModelQuestao" a "ViewQuestao" é aquela que sabe como exibir o model.
- controller. O controller é o reponsável por receber os dados do usuário  e decidir o que fazer com eles. Ele vai processar requisições, transformar dados delas (o que vem em GET's e POST's no caso de web) e enviar tudo para o model apropriado.

## porque usar?

A principal vantagem é a separação clara de responsabilidades que você tem entre as camadas, cada uma delas é responsável por uma parte do trabalho que sua aplicação faz, esse tipo de divisão é algo essencial se você quer trabalhar grandes quantidades de código ou em equipe. Uma aplicação "grude" onde você tem um arquivo/classe que faz tudo (processa requisições, manipula estruturas de dados das entidades, exibe o conteúdo, etc) pode funcionar bem e fazer tudo que você precisa, mas é um sacrifício para dar manutenção, principalmente se você não foi o cara que criou ela (e 6 meses sem olhar para o código que escreveu vai te fazer achar que foi outra pessoa).

O fato de este padrão ser amplamente difundido é também um bônus, é muito mais fácil você mergulhar em código alheio que usa um modelo arquitetural com o qual você já é familiar do que em um que foi estruturado de acordo com o gosto do autor.

## como usar?

É interessante que você esteja falando sobre como queria fazer um sistema completamente com OOP e tenha acabado em MVC pois **você não precisa implementar MVC usando orientação a objetos**, o padrão está em um nível de abstração superior a programação OO || funcional || estruturada. É verdade que quase sempre você vai achar referências a MVC usando OO, contudo isso é porque OO é onipresente hoje em dia.

Para te dar um exemplo de MVC em código: suponha que você por algum motivo decidiu que é uma boa ideia fazer um aplicativo concorrente do stackoverflow, e aí pensando no problema decidiu começar ele pela entidade "Questão", seu model poderia ser o seguinte:

```
namespace Model\Questao;

function build($id, $titulo, $ultimaEdicao, $gratificacao, $criadorId)) {
    // validamos nosso modelo
    validate($id, $titulo, $ultimaEdicao, $gratificacao, $criador);

    return [
        'id' => $id,
        'titulo' => $id,
        'ultimaEdicao' => $ultimaEdicao,
        'gratificacao' => $gratificacao,
        'criador' => $criadorId
    ];
}

function validate($id, $titulo, $ultimaEdicao, $gratificacao, $criadorId) {
    if (!is_int($id) || $id < 0) {
        throw new Exception('Id inválida');
    }
    else if (mb_strlen($titulo) < 5) {
        throw new Exception('Títulos de questões devem ter no minímo 5 caracters.');
    }
    else if ($ultimaEdicao && !ehUmaDatetimeValida($ultimaEdicao)) {
        throw new Exception('Data de última edição inválida');
    }
    else if ($gratificacao && $gratificacao < 50 || $gratificacao > 200) {
        throw new Exception('Gratificações devem ser entre 50 e 200 pontos.');
    }
    else if (!is_int($criadorId) || $criadorId <= 0) {
        throw new Exception('Usuário inválido.');
    }
}

function create($questao) {
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO question (title, creationDate, fk_id_user)';
    getDb()->query(
        $sql, [$questao['titulo'], date("Y-m-d H:i:s"), $questao['criador']]
    );

    // checar se a query deu certo, talvez carregar a id no objeto para uso, etc
}

function update ($questao) {
    // mesma coisa do create, mas dessa vez UPDATE ... WHERE id=$questao['id']
}

function recuperarTodas() {
    // faz um select na db e retorna um array de questões ( build(dados..) )
}

function recuperarPorId($id) {
    // faz um select na db e constrói a questão a ser retornada com "build"
}

// delete, getQuestaoByName, etc
```

Note como o model questão conhece as regras para construção e validação de uma questão, além de saber como persistir, atualizar, deletar e recuperar questões do banco. Agora para a View:

```
namespace View\Questao;

use Model\Questao as M;

function exibirTodasAsQuestoes() {
    echo '<table>';
    echo '<thead><tr>Id</tr><tr>Titulo</tr><tr>Última edição</tr><tr>Gratificação</tr><tr>Criador</tr></thead>';
    echo '<tbody>';
    foreach(M\recuperarTodas() as $questao) {
        echo '<tr><td>' . $questão['id'] . '</td><td>' . $questão['titulo'] . '</td>' . 
            '<td>' . $questão['ultimaEdicao'] . '</td><td>' . $questão['gratificacao'] . '</td>' . 
            '<td>' . $questão['criador'] . '</td></tr>';
    } 
    echo '</tbody></table>':
}

function exibirQuestao($questao) {
    // sabe como exibir o html correto para uma questão específica
}

function exibirErro($error) {
    echo // exibe o erro apropriadamente formatado
}

// etc
```

A view sabe como exibir a questão em diferentes contextos (listagem, exibição, etc) e se comunica com o model 
que conhece a estrutura interna de "Questão" e sabe como recuperar os dados da camada de persistência. 
Finalmente o controller:

```
namespace Controller\Questao;

use Model\Questao as M;
use View\Questao as V;

function post() {

    // também faz Sanitização do conteúdo, checa se não possui conteúdo malicioso, etc
    // todo o processamento que não é específico deste modelo.
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $titulo = $_POST['titulo'];
    $ultimaEdicao = $_POST['ultimaEdicao'];
    $gratificacao = $_POST['gratificacao'];
    $criadorId = $_POST['criador'];

    try { 
        $questao = M\build($id, $titulo, $ultimaEdicao, $gratificacao, $criadorId);
        if ($questao['id']) { // possui id, atualizar
            M\update($questao);
        }
        else { // sem ID, criar
            M\create($questao);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        V\exibirErro($e->getMessage());
    }
}

function exibir() {
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $questao = M\recuperarPorId($id);
    V\exibirQUestao($questao);
}

// etc
```

O controller recebe os requests do usuário, faz processamentos gerais nos dados deste request, chama as funções certas no model e exibe dados pela view se necessário.

Note como eu não usei classes, apenas namespaces (porque afinal trabalhar com globais é dor de cabeça certa) e funções, mas você poderia facilmente transportar esse modelo para um OO ou até retirar os namespaces se desejar, o importante é entender que se pode implementar MVC em qualquer paradigma desejado.

obs: o código pode conter alguns erros, não leve ele a risca pois é só um exemplo.

## devo usar?

Qual o tamanho da sua aplicação? quem vai desenvolver ela? é só você? quem vai dar manutenção nela? depende de muitos fatores, se você está fazendo um projeto que vai jogar fora depois (tipo um trabalho de faculdade) ou algo realmente muito simples talvez seja [overengineering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overengineering). Contudo se você planeja fazer uma aplicação grande e que vai precisar manter por um longo período de tempo vale a pena considerar este padrão, lembrando é claro que existem outras alternativas e MVC é apenas uma delas.

Comment: Bom exemplo e +1 por evidenciar que MVC não depende de OO ou outro paradigma.

Comment: @rray eu ia falar a mesma coisa, inclusive conheço um framework (bem ruinzinho por sinal) que tem boa parte sendo estrutural. Gostei da parte que citou *"se você está fazendo um projeto que vai jogar fora depois"* :)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento o CI? xD não sei como está o v3 mas os anteriores ...

Comment: @rray é o kissmvc, os "controllers" (ou melhor os actions) são funções, sem classes, apesar que tem abstração de uma classe controller, mas é bem bugado e "estranho", só usei uma vez pra brincar, talvez eu esteja enganado :)

Comment: @rray hehehe Até que o CI3 tá legalzinho, testei a alguns dias

Answer (score 5):

## Como e para que usar MVC no PHP?

O melhor link que eu posso te dar e que vai abrir a sua mente é este http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/from_flat_php_to_symfony2.html
A tradução para português encontra-se aqui: http://andreiabohner.org/symfony2docs/book/from_flat_php_to_symfony2.html

### Mas o que é MVC?

MVC é apenas um padrão de projeto. Existem vários padrões diferentes, sugeridos por livros, artigos, empresas de tecnologia e desenvolvedores de grande prestígio.

Você, como desenvolvedor, programador ou arquiteto de software não é obrigado a utilizar nenhum padrão de projeto oferecido por outros. Você, como ser pensante, pode criar seu próprio padrão de projeto.

### Afinal, o que é padrão de projeto?

Um padrão de projeto é apenas a forma de definir como seu código deve ser organizado e como ele deve se comportar.

Quando **UM** ou mais desenvolvedores decidem criar um projeto, dividir esforços e juntar as partes que cada um fez, é ideal que defina-se um padrão de projeto. Assim, no futuro, quando os códigos precisarem ser integrados para formar a aplicação, é mais fácil entender o que cada desenvolvedor fez.

Também, no futuro, quando você precisar voltar num código antigo para corrigir um bug, se seu código segue um padrão de projeto, é mais fácil de você ler e relembrar o que o código deveria fazer.

Dê uma lida neste artigo do wikipedia: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padr%C3%A3o_de_projeto_de_software

Recomendo também que você compre, e estude, um bom livro de arquitetura de software. Um muito bom é "Engenharia de Software: uma abordagem profissional" do Roger Pressman.

Answer (score 2):

O OOP e MVC são coisas distintas. MVC é um padrão de design onde basicamente separa-se as camadas de responsabilidades onde o M representa a lógica de negócio, o C representa o controlador e V, a interface. É possível, sem problema algum, estruturar códigos no padrão MVC sem usar orientação a objetos. O próprio criador do PHP, Rasmus Lerdorf, há 10 anos atrás, escreveu um artigo do qual foi mal interpretado então ele reescreveu um outro artigo disponível no link: https://toys.lerdorf.com/archives/38-The-no-framework-PHP-MVC-framework.html

As críticas que ele recebeu foram na verdade flames de haters que não gostaram do que ele comentou no artigo original. No artigo original ele literalmente descia a lenha (fazia crítica severa) ao "irracional" uso de OOP no PHP. Aí já viu, recebeu uma tempestade de haters que não entenderam o que ele quis dizer, como se ele estivesse dizendo que o OOP fosse algo inútil e desnecessário.

Por fim, quando pensar em MVC, não pense em OOP. O MVC sequer é um objeto. É meramente um padrão de design de projeto para organizar os códigos e rotinas.

Muito provavelmente você já usa um pouco de MVC sem querer. Talvez com uma violação ou outra, mas de qualquer forma já faz isso. Exemplo, se vc escreve os códigos PHP sem misturar com CSS, HTML, JS, dentre outros, já está fazendo uma boa separação entre a view e os controladores. O ponto que mais confunde é saber separar o que é o controller e o que é o model.

Parte da pergunta que fizeste enfatiza o OOP, porém, como esse não é o foco em questão, restringirei a resposta ao MVC.

As respostas existentes já dizem bastante, portanto, para não repetir o óbvio, vamos diretamente a um exemplo prático e simples, sem uso de classes. Algo que qualquer programador PHP inciante que sabe ao menos usar variáveis e funções, consegue compreender.

```
<?php
/*
Bootstrap
*/
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Tokyo');
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('log_errors', true);
ini_set('html_errors', false);
ini_set('display_errors', true);
define('CHARSET', 'UTF-8');
ini_set('default_charset', CHARSET);
mb_http_output(CHARSET);
mb_internal_encoding(CHARSET);

/*
Controller
*/
function Control()
{
    $m = null;
    if (isset($_REQUEST['m'])) {
        $m = trim($_REQUEST['m']);
    }
    if (empty($m)) {
        $m = 'Foo';
    }

    /* 
    Call the model
    */
    $f = 'Model'.$m;
    $data = $f();

    /* 
    Call the view
    */
    $f = 'View'.$m;
    $f($data);
}

/*
Foo Model
*/
function ModelFoo()
{
    return array(
        'body' => array('a', 'b', 'c'),
        'header_charset' => CHARSET,
        'header_content_type' => 'text/html'
    );
}

/*
Foo View
*/
function ViewFoo($data)
{
    header('Content-Type: '.$data['header_content_type'].'; charset='.$data['header_charset']);
    echo '<html>
    <body>
        Foo Page<br />'.
        $data['body'][0].$data['body'][1].$data['body'][2].'
    </body>
    </html>';
}

/*
Bar Model
*/
function ModelBar()
{
    return array(
        'body' => array('a', 'b', 'c'),
        'header_charset' => CHARSET,
        'header_content_type' => 'text/html'
    );
}

/*
Bar View
*/
function ViewBar($data)
{
    header('Content-Type: '.$data['header_content_type'].'; charset='.$data['header_charset']);
    echo '<html>
    <body>
        Bar Page<br />'.
        $data['body'][0].$data['body'][1].$data['body'][2].'
    </body>
    </html>';
}

/*
Start the engine
*/
Control();

/*
Para executar, acesse pelo browser 
http://localhost/mvc/?m=Bar 
ou http://localhost/mvc/ 
e veja o resultado desse mini framework.
*/
```

No exemplo não fiz nenhuma validação para evitar encher com muitos códigos e demonstrar as camadas MVC com mais clareza. Portanto, esteja ciente de que precisa criar códigos consistentes e seguros. O exemplo acima é meramente ilustrativo.

Nesse aplicativo temos 2 models e cada model tem 1 view, portanto, 2 models e 2 views.

Há um único controlador, o qual decide o que fazer com as entradas provindas do usuário. As requisições GET/POST. No exemplo acima simplifiquei com `$_REQUEST`.

Um problema muito comum de encontrar é o mal uso do padrão onde aplicam partes do modelo de negócios dentro do controller ou partes da view dentro do model ou mesmo do controller.

## Exemplos de erros muito comuns

**Violando o controller**

```
function anti_injection_sql($str){
    // Suponha que aqui tenha uma rotina para tratar injeções sql, das mais bizarras e sem sentido. 
    return $str;
}

function Control()
{
    $m = null;
    if (isset($_REQUEST['m'])) {
        $m = trim($_REQUEST['m']);
    }

    /*
    Por quê fazer filtragem contra sql injection aqui? 
    Não é responsabilidade do Controller, a menos que esse parâmetro seja usado pelo controller para buscar no banco de dados algo específico somente do controller.
    Mas enfim, normalmente é desnecessário. Está apenas violando o MVC e corrompendo a entrada original.

    Como aqui não há nenhuma consulta a banco de dados, não faz sentido.
    */
    $m = anti_injection_sql($m);

    if (empty($m)) {
        $m = 'Foo';
    }
```

**Violando o model**

```
function ModelFoo()
{
    /*
    Observe o código HTML `<b></b>` dentro do array que será enviado para a view. Ainda estamos no Model, não deveria ter nada de HTML formatando o conteúdo da view aqui.
    */
    return array(
        'body' => array('<b>a</b>', 'b', 'c'),
        'header_charset' => CHARSET,
        'header_content_type' => 'text/html'
    );
}
```

**Violando a view**

```
/*
Bootstrap
*/
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Tokyo');
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);

/*
Aqui dispara um cabeçalho que informa o tipo do conteúdo e conjunto de caracteres.
Isso torna a aplicação inteira "engessada" pois se precisar exibir uma view com um content-type ou charset diferente?
E se precisar usar funções como session_start() que conflitarão com cabeçalhos previamente despachados?
Nesses casos, com certeza vai acabar resolvendo com mais gambiarras e, é o que acontece normalmente.
O cabeçalho faz parte da view, portanto, é responsabilidade dessa camada.
*/
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8);
```

## A view é burra?

Aqui temos também uma pequena confusão, pois, no exemplo misturamos PHP com HTML na view e ao mesmo tempo afirmamos que no MVC não deve-se misturar o PHP com HTML.

O fato é, a view precisa ser compilada de alguma forma. Aqui, como lidamos com PHP, usamos o próprio PHP para compilar. A fim de tornar o exemplo o mais simples possível, evitei usar um exemplo complexo com compilador de template pois tornaria o exemplo muito complexo. Basicamente, a view não pode ser "burra". Afinal, o HTML não é uma linguagem de programação onde podemos usar estrutura de controle de fluxo, laços de repetição, dentre outros.

Alternativamente podemos usar JavaScript para controlar a disposição dos dados na view, assim os templates das views estariam 100% livres de códigos PHP.

Para isso existem ferramentas como o jquery template, mustache, handlebars, dentre outros.

Como nem tudo são flores encontramos um impecilho, pois para construir um website precisamos nos preocupar com SEO (mecanismos de busca). Os mecanismos de busca não compilam o JavaScript tornando um problema o uso de JavaScript como template engine. Mas nesse ponto entramos numa outra discussão que não vem ao caso discutir aqui.

Resumindo, não interprete de forma literal "não misturar o php com html". Isso deve ser interpretado como "não misture as camadas MVC".

```
function ViewFoo($data)
{
    header('Content-Type: '.$data['header_content_type'].'; charset='.$data['header_charset']);
    echo '<html>
    <body>
        Foo Page<br />'.
        $data['body'][0].$data['body'][1].$data['body'][2].'
    </body>
    </html>';
}
```

Eventualmente haverá situações onde será necessário invocar rotinas dentro da view. Seria uma violação escrever rotinas na view e por isso foi criado algo que conhecemos por "helpers". É um jeito elegante de violar, de fazer uma gambiarra na view de um jeito aceitável.

Os helpers facilitam a montagem das views, como por exemplo, os cabeçalhos HTML, montagem de menus, links, etc.

## Performance

Você deve ter percebido as passagens de parâmetros no controller:

```
/* 
Call the model
*/
$f = 'Model'.$m;
$data = $f();

/* 
Call the view
*/
$f = 'View'.$m;
$f($data);
```

Numa programação em estilo procedural, não faríamos tantas voltas e pouparia processos, memória, etc. Então por quê devo largar mão da performance de um código mais simples para escrever um código mais complexo que consumirá mais memória e processos?

A coisa toda sobre o conceito OOP é reutilizar rotinas de forma inteligente. Na verdade você passa a escrever menos códigos. Passa a se concentrar mais na lógica de negócios (Model) do que nos processos de controle. Numa programação procedural, praticamente reinventamos a roda para cada nova lógica de negócio. São processos repetitivos que, quando não possuem uma organização, torna a manutenção num pesadelo.

No trecho de código acima, por exemplo, poderíamos eliminar o uso de uma nova variável `$data = $f();` trocando-a por uma propriedade pública de uma classe.
Evitando assim transportar os mesmos dados em objetos diferentes.

## Quando usar? Devo usar? Onde entraria o OOP?

Como pode ver, nesse pequeno e ridículo framework encontramos diversas coisas que precisam de implementações tornando-o bastante complexo. Imagine num sistema mediano, qual o tamanho da complexidade em escrever códigos organizados e consistentes?

Numa programação estrutural, a quantidade de códigos e conceitos tornam-se inviáveis para manutenção mesmo em sistemas pequenos. Por isso existe o OOP e seus diversos conceitos e paradigmas. A decisão em usar um conceito X ou Y depende do programador. Não há uma lei que diga como devemos escrever os códigos. O que existe são recomendações do que fazer e do que aplicar numa situação A ou B.

Óbvio que não vamos exagerar. Se você precisa criar um site HTML de 1 página com um formulário de contato de 3 campos, é óbvio que não vai precisar usar OOP. Um simples `$_POST`, `isset()`, `if else` e `mail()` já resolve.

Answer (score 0):

**O MVC serve para quê?**

Para tentar colocar o programador dentro de uma caixa chamada "**PADRÃO**". Dá até arrepios ao ouvir esta palavra. Eca!

Usei o MVC só um dia, achei legal, bem pensado. Mas... Não é para mim!

*No início usei Drupal, era legal, mas aí pensei para quê todas essas classes e funções que não usarei?*

Não tem lógica isso! Tentei o *Wordpress* e a mesma pergunta. Fui de *PHP* puro mesmo. Desenvolvi apenas o que irei utilizar e, vez por outra mudo as classes e funções para que se tornem mais compactas e façam a mesma coisa. Sempre aparece uma ideia diferente, um jeito diferente, melhor e mais rápido de fazer a mesma coisa. Isso é demais! Um *CMS* não nos permite isso. Não existe um jeito certo de fazer nada, existe sim o teu jeito de fazer as  coisas.

*Que método permite que te soltes?*

Que te permite a liberdade de fazer sem limitações. Quando se aprende a programar sem professor, na unha não se tem nem o hábito de fazer um diagrama de fluxo. Alguns de nós não tem nem mesmo o hábito de formatar o código(eu).

Uso um editor de texto no *Linux*, super básico chamado `Medit`, não foi feito para programar, mas deixa qualquer código de programação colorido de acordo com a linguagem. Adoro ele!

*Parece antiquado!?*

Alguns diriam que uma *IDE* seria mais prático. Mas não seria melhor digitar cada função que se irá utilizar?

Cada um tem sua opinião e toda opinião deve ser respeitada pois é tida sob um ponto de vista. Mas a resposta certa é: Não existe um 'tem que'. Padrão é algo cunhado para que as pessoas não ousem demais. É como os *ANTOLHOS* que se colocam nos cavalos para que ele não olhem para o lado e façam apenas aquilo que se espera deles - ser guiado pelo condutor - sem ver nada ao seu redor a não ser o caminho à sua frente. É triste isso, mas é isso mesmo. Experimente e tome a tua decisão, pois o que pode ser bom para um é, na verdade, ruim ou fatal para outros!

Comment: Hoje, quase um ano após a pergunta, e já conhecendo muito mais sobre o assunto e outros, vejo que o MVC é algo essencial, mas não só o MVC, mas sim qualquer outro padrão de desenvolvimento, na organização do código nem se fale, quando está associado a um framework então o ganho de tempo é infinitamente maior. Sobre IDE, concordo. Sobre a resposta, fugiu um pouco do contexto central da pergunta.

Comment: Acho que o usuário confundiu CMS com MVC.