# aonde montar a tabela em um projeto MVC PHP com ajax?

Tags: php, ajax, mvc

Dentro da model eu tenho uma série de tratativas para mostrar o resultado final.

```
//CONTROLLER
public function index(){    
    $this->view->render("views/index.php");
}

public function read(){
    $data = array();
    $data['id'] = $_POST['id'];
    $this->model->showAlgo($data);
}

//MODEL

public function showAlgo($data){
    //Faz um select com o  $data['id'] e retorna uma a table já montada
    $resultadoDaQuery = "<table><tr><td>".$resultado['algumacolunadobanco']."</td></tr></table>";
    echo json_encode($resultadoDaQuery);
}
```

script:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "nome/read",
    type: "POST",
    success: function(dados){
        //monta os dados aqui e envia pro html via jquery
    },
    error: function(){}
});
```

- qual é a maneira correta de montar o resultado?
- posso fazer isso no model como no exemplo acima e enviar diretamente para o ajax (no `success`)?
- ou deve-se montar a tabela dentro do ajax (na função `success`)?

Answer (score 0):

O código HTML nesse caso deveria estar na View.

Há uma confusão geral também sobre o que é model e view, tal como o uso do controller.

Leia esse tópico recente:

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/116422/4793